# What tool can I use to manage my Python and SQL Workflow?

Tags: python, sql, workflow, platform

For context: I'm new the technical side of this field of my work.

So here's my process:

I have a file that I need to pull from Filezilla then I need to process the file using a python script and send the output table to an Oracle Database. I then run a big SQL script that pulls data from high volume tables (Oracle SQL Developer) and that produces a final table. Then I run a python script algorithm that connects to that table and produce a file to be sent back to filezilla. I can do everything here manually. But I'm looking to automate my process.

**So here's my workflow:**
Filezilla -> Python -> OracleSQL Developer -> Pthon -> Filezilla

I've been looking up on what tools to use that can manage workflows in one platform? I've heard of airflow but not really sure if it is capable of this? I unfortunately cannot do it on platforms like databricks as it would require transfering huge volumes of data everyday on the SQL part.

Comment: why don't you connect it directly using mysql connector or a similar tool ?

Comment: I do use CxOracle to connect final tables from python to sql and sql to python. But for the SQL script part, that is a big sql data modeling script that involves several table which is why I had to move out and run the sql script outside. I want to be able to manage the entire workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Airflow is a platform to orchestrate (build, maintain and manage) exactly you have described - workflows. In your case, Airflow provides a lot of operators (like tasks templates) to build your own workflow - PythonOperator, SFTPOperator, OracleOperator and so on. In Airflow UI, you can access a lot of information about your [workflows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muhcL.png)

IMO, a big Airflow drawbacks is that it has a steep learning curve. And, depending what you plan to do, it can become a case of using a sledgehammer to crack a nut. Both drawbacks comes from Airflow flexibility. If you wanna test, see the documentation [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/index.html)

If you plan to orchestrate several other workflows and it's is important to manage them, I advise you to keep going and use Airflow. Otherwise, build a Python script with the steps you described and put in a CRON job.